# finding different elements in class

Tags: c++, class

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Lek{
    private:
        int sifra;
        string ime;
        string proizvoditel;
        int cena;
        int kolicina;
    public:
        Lek(){

        }
        void postavuvanje(int s, string i, string p, int c, int k){
            sifra = s;
            ime = i;
            proizvoditel = p;
            cena = c;
            kolicina = k;
        }

        int vratiSifra(){
            return sifra;
        }

        string vratiIme(){
            return ime;
        }

        string vratiProizvoditel(){
            return proizvoditel;
        }

        int vratiCena(){
            return cena;
        }

        int vratiKolicina(){
            return kolicina;
        }

        void pecati(){
            cout << sifra << " " << ime << " " << proizvoditel << " " << cena << " " << kolicina << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    Lek Apteka[100];
    int n;
    cout << "Vnesi go brojot na lekovi" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int sifra;
    string ime;
    string proizvoditel;
    int cena;
    int kolicina;

    // here we are inputting the values for the array of objects.
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> sifra;
        cin >> ime;
        cin >> proizvoditel;
        cin >> cena;
        cin >> kolicina;
        Apteka[i].postavuvanje(sifra, ime, proizvoditel, cena, kolicina);
    }

    // this is part to find the name of the element with the lowest price.
    int najmala_cena = Apteka[0].vratiCena();
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
        if(Apteka[i].vratiCena() < najmala_cena){
            najmala_cena = Apteka[i].vratiCena();
            index = i;
        }
    }

    cout << Apteka[index].vratiIme() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have managed to solve the problem of finding the element with lowest price.However, I have to find all elements who have 'proizvoditel' "X" and find how many different names (ime) does it have.

Let's say we have the following input by user:

```
1
PillX
HospitalY
125
2

2
PillY
HospitalY
225
4

3
PillZ
HospitalY
590
1

4
PillX
HospitalY
125
8
```

So, basically, those are the attributes of 4 objects of the class and we have the same 'proizvoditel' for all the pills, called "HospitalY" and we have to find how many different pills does it have, so it has 3, since PillX already exists and is not counted the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making an array of lists for each proizvoditel, i.e an array that it's i-th cell conatins a list of all the pills for that proizvoditel.

Each time you find an existing proizvoditel , check if the pill is in the list and if it is increase the counter.

You can try std::map but you'll probably have to write a compare function for the classes it holds.